# How to recalculate variance/covariance matrix adding a overdispersion term in glmm?

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, overdispersion

When models suffer from overdispersion, a solution is to calculate the dispersion parameter (using c_hat or dispersion_glmer in R for example). Then multiply the variance/covarianze matrix of estimates by this dispersion parameter. It recalculates estandard errors and gives corrected p-values. In GLM, you can call the function summary(model,dispersion=XX). Is there a way to do that for GLMM (glmer function)?